# javascript - check if array is null?

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to check if var match is empty but im not having any luck. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var url = document.getElementById("defineNewURL").value;
var urlReg;


var subject = url.toString();
var regex = /^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/
match = regex.exec(subject);

if(typeof match == 'undefined'){
    urlReg = url;
}else{
    urlReg = match[6];
}
```

Comment: please add the array.

Answer (score 1):

`//.exec` returns `null` when there is no match,
and an object when there is a match.
Since all objects are *truthy*, and `null` is *falsy*,
you can write the condition like this:

```
if (match) {
    urlReg = match[6];
} else {
    urlReg = url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`regex.exec` not return undefined but null. And in your code:

```
typeof match
```

return `object`

Look on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

And try make your code like this:

```
var url = document.getElementById("defineNewURL").value;
var urlReg;


var subject = url.toString();
var regex = /^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/
match = regex.exec(subject);

if(match == null){
    urlReg = url;
}else{
    urlReg = match[6];
}
```